# How to execute a command with admin privileges and access to files of the logged in user?

Tags: macos, sudo, privileges

I have some problems understanding `sudo`. I am logged in on a terminal as an non-admin/non-root user. This "normal" user is not in the sudoers file (and shouldnt be, in my opinion).

Now I try to execute a command that needs admin/root privileges and also access to directories of my normal user – therefore I am not able
to simply `su` into an admin or root user.

In my understanding `sudo -u root` should do the trick – however
it doesn't accept the password for `root` (or admin if I try with my normal
admin user). It only accepts the password of the "normal" user which seems
to indicate that the `-u username` option doesn't work the way I expect it to
work.

My expectation is that `sudo -u root some_command` executes `some_command`
with the privileges of root and therefore it asks also for the password of root.
Obviously not.

**TL;DR:** How do I execute any command that requires admin
privileges AND has access to the files of the "logged in (normal) user" without
adding the normal user to the sudoers file?

I have enabled the root user under Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 13):

`sudo` always requires the executing user's password (and requires that you have specific permissions to do this, i.e. are one of the `sudoers`).

`su` requires the password of the target account (`root` by default, but root account has no password on OS X by default). If you use `su` instead, you can enter the destination account's password and execute a command using that user's privileges.

```
su -c some_cmd # as root
su username -c some_cmd # as username
```

<sup>This works by passing all arguments after the user name to the destination account's login shell. Shells usually support `-c <commands>` arguments. In GNU coreutils `su`, there's an actual `-c command` argument to `su` that can be placed before the user name.</sup>

---

You can `su` to another user account (using the other user account's password), and `sudo` from there, provided that other account is a `sudoer`.

If you want neither to enter another account's password, nor give your regular account `sudoers` permissions, you're pretty much out of options unless you consider SSH with key authentication or something like that.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for the answer.

I am not sure if I do understand you correct.
As far as I can tell if I su into root I will loose access to the files of the initially logged in user - however this is exactly what I need.

Let me be more concrete: I am using npm (node package manager) to install a self written package into the global package registry on my machine. For this to do i need access to "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/..." which the loggedin user (let say "robert") doesnt have. The package resides in "~/my_package".
su doesnt help as it has no access to this folder (next comment)

Comment: and adding "robert" to the sudoers file seems like total overkill to me.

Comment: @robertj Root can access all users' files. So if you `su` without specifying a user, you're  good.

Comment: I'm running OS X 10.8.3 and 'su -c' is not recognized as a valid option for me...: "su: illegal option -- c"

Comment: @Daps0l Fixed, try the changed command.

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to combine this with sudo AND only have to type in the (same) password 1 time? Something like this:  su username -c 'sudo some_cmd'

Comment: @Daps0l Not that I know of, except by allowing *username* to run `some_cmd` as root all the time (look for `NOPASSWD` in `man sudoers`). (If the down vote I received for this answer is yours, I'd appreciate if you could undo that)

Comment: Sudo doesn't always require password. Calling sudo updates timestamp and allows to run sudo without giving password for a couple of minutes (this varies between OSes).

Answer (score 6):

Unless you really "need" to maintain a separate root user on Mac OS X, it's often much easier to just get a root shell using `sudo -s`

In your case, non-admin users are not included in /etc/sudoers - so you would have to add by hand the users/groups you intend to have sudo accept.

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Once that's done, sudo will inherits almost all of the nice things from your shell like PATH and other variables, but elevates your non-admin user instantly to root. The downside of enabling root is time and the security risk of someone actually logging in locally or remotely as root.

Keep in mind, `sudo` is asking for the password of the user that logged in to the loginwindow screen. `su -` wants the password of the root account, `sudo -s` uses privilege escalation to use the current user's password to become root without needing any (or in your case, *the actual*) root password.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a standard account (usually for security reasons) and you know an administrator username and password, you can do `su -l admin_user`. After entering the password, you are now, for all effects, acting as that administrator. Then you can `sudo` to your heart's content. Now, just `logout` to go back to your original plain account.

Answer (score 0):

my terminal executable cannot achieve what it will itself, but by doing that annoying operation:

Open App>Utility>Terminal.app;

~ user$ sudo /PATH_TO_TERMINAL_EXEC

Get administrator privileges;

Done.

... That's what is inside terminal_executable

```
#!/bin/bash

echo PATCHING HOSTS FILE...!
echo  >> /etc/hosts
echo \# IsPatched >> /etc/hosts
echo 127.0.0.1 somewebsite.com >> /etc/hosts
```

... What I have already tried is

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpvar=$(whoami)
echo TRYING!
su $tmpvar echo 127.0.0.1 somesite.com >> /etc/hosts
```

or

```
su cuskus -c sudo -s echo 127.0.0.1 somesite.com >> /etc/hosts
```

just got #!/bin/bash window after asking for password but cannot execute any code because of privileges.

Comment: This solved my problem: http://superuser.com/a/1021174/622740