# Mac OS X Terminal assistance

Tags: mac, hard-drive, osx-lion

I have a damaged internal hard drive that I would like to erase. I have installed Lion on a USB external hard drive and am able to start Lion; however, using Disk Utility I am not able to format, erase or repair my damaged volume or hard drive. So I have starting looking at Terminal for the answer. I have tried quite a few avenues without any joy.

When I try verifyVolume on the disk Lion was installed on I get

```
Invalid volume free block count
(It should be 24007653 instead of 23768745)
```

I hunted around on the internet and found that

```
fsck_hfs -r /dev/disk1s2
```

or

```
fsck_hfs -f /dev/disk1s2
```

worked for someone else; however, I tried both and received

```
** /dev/rdisk1s2 (NO WRITE)
Can't open /dev/rdisk1s2: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me change the permission of the drive or better still help me and tell me what the fsck_hfs command will be doing?

Comment: You must be root to run administrative tasks. See this http://superuser.com/questions/335057/how-to-execute-a-command-with-admin-privileges-and-access-to-files-of-the-logged . Also try searching in the future and good luck!

Comment: Yep thanks...unfortunately I tried running under sudo but no commands have worked. Any further help appreciated

Comment: Troubleshooting is not really the format here. Check the FAQ.