# Problems with sudo privileges as admin in OSX

Tags: macos, permissions, administrator, sudo

I am a admin on my Mac with OSX and I have enabled root user. When I try to use the terminal without typing sudo it does not seem to recognise my privileges as an admin, but it works fine if I type sudo and enter my password.

I also have tried to manually give the sudo privileges in the /etc/sudoers file, but still no luck.

Running an installation through NPM all I get is: "npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need the root to be enabled in OS X to use sudo [in fact, it's very much **not** recommended], any admin can do it by default. What's probably stopping you is System Integrity Protection [SIP] See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really/193379#193379

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok, now I disabled SIP and rebooted. But I still get the same problem. Can´t install via NPM without sudo.

Comment: Please use something like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). It’s easy to manage and won’t break your system.

Comment: @DanielB Use Homebrew instead of NPM you mean?

Comment: No. Use Homebrew to install NodeJS, which includes NPM.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behaviour in OS X, even if you are an Administrator, you will not be able to write to anything under `/`, apart from **your** home directory without prefixing your command with `sudo`. Even if you do use `sudo` or `sudo su -` (to gain access to a root shell), you will not be able to make changes to anything under `/usr` (except `/usr/local`), `/bin`. `/sbin`, `/etc`, etc... without disabling rootless mode/SIP (System Integrity Protection) from recovery mode. You can disable it using the command `csrutil disable`. Note that rootless mode is new in OS X 10.11 El Capitan. If you still can't get `npm` working with `sudo`, try using `sudo whoami` and check that it outputs `root`, and use `sudo -u root`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah....  Being an admin, basically gives you sudo abilities, but you are still not root.   I.e.  your account is not uid=0.   That's the only root user.   You have three choices.

1. Use sudo (like you have been)
2. You can su to root like:
   sudo su root -
3. You can change your UID to 0.

I would recommend #1.

Comment: I did just that and it still does not work. I did just as you describe. Why is that?

Comment: It may be a different issue... let me think about it.